# Setting attributes for the first column's contents with jquery

Tags: jquery, traversal, tree-traversal, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

I have the following table which is loaded dynamically into a `<div>`.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s0p9.png]

Now I am trying to traverse into the table as to disable all the input fields in the first column titled "index". How would I go about that?

What I have come up with is the following, but it fails:

```
$('#output').find('tr').each().find('td').first().find('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as well.

```
$('#output tr td:first-child input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Everything in one selector. Tested in chrome only

http://jsfiddle.net/QGdJF/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(1) input').prop('disabled',true)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4YqJ7/)**

Since you didn't post the HTML for your table, I offer a generic example. You may be able to replace the selector with `$('#output td:nth-child(1) input')` depending on your exact code.